# RUN command not called in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image (Ubuntu)
FROM dockerfile/python

# Install socat
RUN \
  cd /opt && \
  wget http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/download/socat-1.7.2.4.tar.gz && \
  tar xvzf socat-1.7.2.4.tar.gz && \
  rm -f socat-1.7.2.4.tar.gz && \
  cd socat-1.7.2.4 && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN \
  start-stop-daemon --quiet --oknodo --start --pidfile /run/my.pid --background --make-pidfile \
  --exec /opt/socat-1.7.2.4/socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyMY,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 \
  TCP-LISTEN:9334,reuseaddr,fork

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

I build an image from this Dockerfile and run it like this:

```
docker run -d -t -i myaccount/socat_test
```

After this I login into the container and check if socat daemon is running. But it is not. I just started playing around with docker. Am I misunderstanding the concept of Dockerfile? I would expect docker to run the socat command when the container starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing `RUN` and `CMD`. The `RUN` command is meant to build up the docker container, as you correctly did with the first one. The second command will also executed when building the container, but not when running it. If you want to execute commands when the docker container is started, you ought to use the `CMD` command.

More information can be found [in the Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/). For instance, you could also use `ENTRYPOINT` in stead of `CMD`.

Comment: Can you help me translating my RUN start-stop-daemon command to CMD? I am a bit confused with the syntax.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should but it inside a startup script. But I wished I could wrap this inside the Dockerfile. I will open another question on that topic.

Comment: Containers are not full VM's.    start-stop-daemon is not the right way.

Comment: @artworkadシ: Just make a list with the "words" of the command separated. As if you called `String.split` on it. `CMD ["start-stop-daemon", "--quiet", ...]`. You should consider running your program in foreground as @user2105103 suggested though. Docker's `-d` takes care of the daemonizing.